# Retrieving data from 2 different database servers

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

I have 3 different database servers. Let's call them A, B and C. I need to take database from A and B (these are different database servers) and put them together in 3rd database server "C".

Do you know how to do it?

Thanks

Comment: May be some people know it. So the answer is yes.

Comment: **WHAT** database system/product??

Comment: Yes, I know how to do it. Do I win a prize?

Comment: you don't need to take mic of it. If you know how to, please help. System is sql ( I put it in tag but forgot to mention again in the text.sorry.)

Comment: What have you attempted? Please check out the FAQ/About page which cover asking questions on SO.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Three options

1. Code something that connects to A & B, consolidate the infomation, connect to C and save it there
2. Use a product that lets you connect to databases read from tables and insert into other tables, something like SQL Server Integration Services and design a flow that does the very same thing than step 1.
3. Depending on the engine, you may be able to make dumps of A&B and load them in C, for example you could dump all data from A&B as insert statements and execute them in C (assuming the tables already exist and that there are no PK conflicts)

That should get you going.

Comment: thank you carlos. it looks like 2nd option is reasonable but I am trying to take a whole database from A and B, and put it in the C database server. This is not a one off job. If I can do it in the ETL ssis package, then I can schedule it. I thought without etl, there could be some sql commands which allows to take backup of A and then B and then restore them in C. To write a project in C# was my last option. it can be an option but I thought I can handle it in SQL database side with a good SQL knowledge person's help.

Comment: If it's something periodic, SSIS is the way to go. Besides, if you need to perform something before throwing the data to C. You may be able to get by with backups, but its risky, clumsy and in the end not worth the effort. Use SSIS, if the appropiate tool.

Comment: I am not expert on SSIS but I will try it now. Thanks a lot carlos.

Comment: Quick question. There is a control called "Back Up Database task" under "Maintenance Plan Tasks" in Business Intelligence - Visual Studio. When i try to use it, it takes backup for A, under a folder which is in server A. Is there any way to take this "A database server's database's backup" to C server by using "Business Intelligence - Visual Studio"?

Comment: Be careful with backups, you're taking structures along with data. And restoring to another server may wipe everthing out.

Comment: :/ I should dig more for database transfer. I am just getting lost in Google

Comment: Read about ssis from the msdn, it'll help you to start

Answer (score 0):

Not without a tool or programmatically.  I think SQL Management studio allows you to query multiple servers as a group, but the result sets come out on screen.

You haven't specified what type of servers your using, so the you are kind of stuck exporting the data from Server A and B to disk, load the data into temporary tables into C and then go from there.

If your using Oracle, you can define Servers A & B as remote servers and query them directly from C.

Answer (score 0):

Which kind of server are you using? There are lots of ways to do such operations.

- If your db's are not too big, you can take exports of the db then combine them into one script file and run it on the 3rd db.
- You can use ETL mechanisms to transfer data.
- If the servers are on the same farm, you can write a query to select data and insert between servers.

If u specify the server types i can give more specific examples.

Comment: sagol ali. ETL yolu ile denicem bakalim...